# Pinout for an SMA Connector

Tags: nfc

I'm trying to connect my antenna to my PN532 chip using an SMA connector but I'm not sure about the pinout. I'm using the following as my [sample schematic](http://www.dz863.com/circuits-20-8390057363-PN532-C1_Fig-10.-Application-diagram-of-PN532-Application-Circuit/) and I want to use the following [SMA connector](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=J502-ND) to connect to an antenna. In the schematic you can see how the two load resistors connect to two pins and then a third pin connects to ground on the antenna. However, I'm not sure how this pinout correlates to the SMA connector meaning, which portions of the SMA connector are Pin1/Pin2/Gnd. Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the spec sheet and mechanical drawing for the connector are linked to directly from the page you linked to above.  The pinout is very clear from that.  Did you look at it at all?  The center pin is the center connection, and the other pins connect to the outside of the coax.  The drawings seem quite clear about this.

Second, that schematic shows 3 connections to the antenna.  if that's what you really want, you can't use a SMA connector since it only has two connections.  SMA is for coax, not balanced line.

Comment: It was a moment of self-doubt when I saw the 3rd pin coming from the antenna and that's why I posted. Thank you for clarifying.